# Excel: Leave formula cell blank when input cell is blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have used a formula to create a point system for my class. My formula is below, and it works great except that when c10 is blank, the score still shows "10" when I'd like it to be blank as well. Could anyone help me edit this formula to fix that tiny error? I can't seem to figure it out.

```
=IF(C10<6.99,10,IF(AND(C10<=7.99,C10>=7),9,IF(AND(C10<=8.99,C10>=8),8,IF(AND(C10<=9.99,C10>=9),7,IF(AND(C10<=10.99,C10>=10),6,IF(AND(C10<=11.99,C10>=11),5,IF(AND(C10<=12.99,C10>=12),4,IF(AND(C10<=13.99,C10>=13),3,IF(AND(C10<=14.99,C10>=14),2,IF(AND(C10<=15.99,C10>=15),1,IF(AND(C10>=16,C10<=100),0)))))))))))
```

Comment: you could just put a test for cell empty around your formula, such as `=IF(trim(c10)="","", rest of formula)` ... that might do it...

Comment: There is still one error I am trying to fix. When c10's value is zero, the score should be zero as well. However, it shows up as 10. I realize this is an error in my formula, but could you help me pinpoint which part I need to fix?

Comment: You could simplify the rest of your formula as well. Why not `=IF(OR(TRIM(C10)="", C10=0),"",MIN(MAX(16-INT(C10),0),10))`

Comment: This looks like a candidate for a VLOOKUP with the option to find the value in a range (as opposed to an exact value). MUCH cleaner and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace "," to ";". You get:

```
=IF(C10<6.99:10:IF(AND(C10<=7.99:c10>=7):9:IF(AND(C10<=8.99:c10>=8):8:IF(AND(C10<=9.99:c10>=9):7:IF(AND(C10<=10.99:c10>=10):6:IF(AND(C10<=11.99:c10>=11):5:IF(AND(C10<=12.99:c10>=12):4:IF(AND(C10<=13.99:c10>=13):3:IF(AND(C10<=14.99:c10>=14):2:IF(AND(C10<=15.99:c10>=15):1:IF(AND(C10>=A10:C16<=100):0)))))))))))
```

I would recommend you http://excelformulabeautifier.com/

Answer (score 0):

Set `C10`'s formula to `=""` and leave the target formula unchanged.